# PHP - how to explode a string using a comma, except situtation when this comma is inside apostrophes?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
$string='
            blah<br>
            @include (\'file_to_load\')
            <br>
            @include (\'file_to_load\',\'param1\',\'param2\',\'param3\')
    ';
```

I'd like to catch (and then replace using preg_replace_callback) all the occurences of "@include" with parameters (e.g. @include ('file_to_load','param1','param2','param3') )

So I do this:

```
$string='
 blah<br>
 @include (\'file_to_load\')
 <br>
 @include (\'file_to_load\',\'param1\',\'param2\')
';
$params=[];
$result = preg_replace_callback(
    '~@include \((,?.*?)\)~',//I catch @include, parenthesis and all between them
    function ($matches) {
        echo '---iteration---';
        $params=explode(',',$matches[1]);//exploding by a comma
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($params);
        echo '</pre>';
        return $matches[1];
    },
    $string
);
```

And everything's fine until a comma appears **inside** a parameter, like here:

```
$string='
    blah<br>
    @include (\'file_to_load\')
    <br>
    @include (\'file_to_load\',\'param1,something\',[\'elem\'=>\'also, a comma\']])
';
```

Here we have a comma inside a "param1" param, now, after exploding with the explode() function it obviously doesn't work like I want.

I there a way to explode() (by using regular expression probably) the string by a comma, but not when the comma is inside apostrophes?

Comment: With the shown examples [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) would be simpler than reinventing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following to split:

```
,(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)
```

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) since [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) does not support regex:

**Code:**

```
$params = preg_split(',(?=([^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)',$matches[1]);
```

Comment: Another idea with preg_split to [skip](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) the quoted stuff `'[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|,` [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jH7eL0/1)

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is *tokenization*. Don't try to split on the commas. Instead, identify each building block of your expression. So you need *matching*, not *splitting*.

For instance, this simple regex:

```
'[^']+'
```

Will match these elements:

```
@include ('file_to_load','param1,something',['elem'=>'also, a comma'])
          \____________/ \________________/  \____/  \_____________/
```

But it may not be sufficient for your case, since you have an array in there, and I assume you have to parse it as well.

So identify each parameter separately:

```
'[^']+'|\[.+?\]
```

```
@include ('file_to_load','param1,something',['elem'=>'also, a comma'])
          \____________/ \________________/ \_______________________/
```

The issue with this approach is that it won't allow you to match nested arrays. If you need to be able to parse that, then the pattern gets more complicated:

```
(?(DEFINE)
  (?<string>'[^']+')
  (?<array> \[ (?: (?&arrayitem) (?> , \s* (?&arrayitem) )* )? \] )
  (?<arrayitem> \s* (?&string) \s* => \s* (?&value) \s* )
  (?<value> (?&string) | (?&array) )
)
(?&value)
```

Yeah, that's a recursive regex but it can actually identify the parameters:

```
@include ('file_to_load','param1,something',['elem'=>'also, a comma','other'=>['nested' => 'array']])
          \___________/  \________________/ \______________________________________________________/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oO3zH2/1)

As I don't know what you're trying to do with the parameters afterwards, you may actually need to write a parser instead of using regular expressions, but that depends on what you'll be trying to do once you split the parameters.

**Side note:** You may need to replace the `'[^']+'` string pattern with something a bit more complicated if you want to be able to escape a quote inside the string.

There are two widely-accepted ways to do this:

- Use a backslash: `'abc\'def'`

  ```
  '(?:[^\\']++|\\.)*'
  ```
- Double the quote: `'abc''def'`

  ```
  '(?:[^']++|'')*'
  ```

Comment: Does this cover realistic cases like `@include ('file_to_load','param1,something',['elem'=>'a, comma and a] brace and an escaped \' single quote'])`? @Luc

Comment: @mick It's supposed to, but the answer is generic, so I didn't include escaping in the main example. See the side note for the needed changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
"\@include[\s]*\([^\)]*\)"
```

This will match

```
@include (\'file_to_load\')
```

and

```
@include (\'file_to_load\',\'param1,something\',[\'elem\'=>\'also, a comma\']])
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please never post "try this" (code-only answers). `[\s]` is more simply expressed as `\s`.  The closing parentheses do not need to be escaped inside or outside of the character class in this pattern.  Nor does the `@` need to be escaped.

Comment: @mickmackusa noted. Thanks. This is an old answer though

Comment: Old answers get copy-pasted by new researchers.  This is why we need to make sure that we always post the best version of our advice that represents the best of our knowledge.  Otherwise, unknowing people will be learning suboptimal programming habits.

Comment: @mickmackusa Okay. I'll make the necessary changes